# Journey Builder - Business Rule Disabled

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

When i access Journey Builder, i get the error:
"Business Rule Disabled

The Journey Builder business rule must be enabled to view this page. Please contact your administrator for further assistance.

Need more help regarding this error? Open a support case through the Help & Training Portal"

I'm an Administrator in my MC Account.

Answer (score 1):

Business rules are add on features in Marketing Cloud. Features likes Journey Builder and SendLogging are business rules , meaning you have to engage support to have them provisioned for your account

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Journey Builder product feature (and appropriate user permissions), log a case with support to turn on those business rules to allow Journey Builder sends.